# Call and analyze 2 lists of files (file1 and file2) in r

Tags: r, lapply

I have 2 lists of files and I want call them simultaneously, each pair [file1(1) and file2(1),...]. But with lapply(file1,file2, FUN) is not permitted. any solutions?

with codes like this:

```
file1=list.files(pattern="rcp45_AU")
file2=list.files(pattern="base_AU_")

FUN = function(file1,file2) {
  db<- fread(file1, header = T)
  dp<- fread(file2, header = T)
  ...
}
#call the function
lapply(file1,file2, FUN)
```

Comment: Try `Map(FUN, file1, file2)`.

Comment: You could try `mapply`.